# Возможно ли вывести в определенном порядке в цикле forEach?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Нужно вывести в цикле в определенном парядке данные, например по определенному ключу по уменьшению значения.

```
var list = '{"success":1,"content":{"content_count":2,"content_list":{"10":{"id":"10","title":"название 10"},"9":{"id":"9","title":"название 9"},"8":{"id":"8","title":"название 8"},"7":{"id":"7","title":"название 7"},"6":{"id":"6","title":"название 6"}}}}';


var obj = list['content'].content_list;
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
    // какой-то код
       search_result += '<p data-id="'+obj[key]['id']+'">'+obj[key]['title']+'</p>';
    });
```

Вывести к примеру по id в таком порядке:

```
10
9
8
7
...
```

Comment: Данные для примера добавьте.

Comment: @KostaB. смотрите. Как пример.

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev Данные для примера добавьте.

Comment: @lgor, щас добавлю json с данными

Comment: @KostaB. добавил json ответ сервера. который потом в цикл заносится...

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev что то новое, сегодня выучили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отсортируйте список в обратном порядке. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

```
var list = '{"success":1,"content":{"content_count":2,"content_list":{"10":{"id":"10","title":"название 10"},"9":{"id":"9","title":"название 9"},"8":{"id":"8","title":"название 8"},"7":{"id":"7","title":"название 7"},"6":{"id":"6","title":"название 6"}}}}';

var obj = JSON.parse(list).content.content_list;
var search_result = "";     
Object.keys(obj).reverse().forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: спасибо! помогли

Answer (score 0):

foreach пробегается по элементам только вперёд (в языке Java) в javascript не знаю, но предполагаю что нельзя. 
используйте for с декрементом